# Passing values to html select from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-select

I have an html select in one of my aspx pages and I would like to assign it the option value from code behind.

```
<select id="pageSize" runat="Server">
        <option value="how to set it from c#?">All</option>
```

I have a property call `MyPageCount` of type int, how can i pass its value here?.

I would appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using an `ASP:DropDownList` rather than a `select` with `runat="server"`?  It will be much easier to work with an actual `DropDownList` via server side code, and it will map to a `select` object when rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<option value="<%: this.MyPageCount.ToString() %>">All</option>
```

If it's inside a data bound control:

```
<option value='<%# Bind("YourField") %>'>All</option>
```

Comment: It's an example of the value you would like to bind, I just changed to use `MyPageCount`

Answer (score 1):

add `runat="server"` and then set `pageSize.Value=MyPageCount;` in codebehind